# How to find closest distance in Pandas given a certain data point?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset which consists of columns like 'DATE_TIME', 'ID', 'VALUE1', 'VALUE2', 'VALUE3', 'VALUE4', 'MODEL','SOLD', 'INSPECTION', 'MODE', 'TIME', 'CYCLE_PART'. ID column values are usually numbers, but there are aplhabetical values too.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import random

df = pd.DataFrame({'DATE_TIME': pd.date_range('2022-11-01', '2022-11-06 23:00:00', freq='20min'),
                   'ID': [random.randrange(1, 20) for n in range(430)]})

df['VALUE1'] = [random.randrange(110, 140) for n in range(430)]
df['VALUE2'] = [random.randrange(50, 60) for n in range(430)]
df['VALUE3'] = [random.randrange(80, 100) for n in range(430)]
df['VALUE4'] = [random.randrange(30, 50) for n in range(430)]

df['MODEL'] = [random.randrange(1, 3) for n in range(430)]

df['SOLD'] = [random.randrange(0, 2) for n in range(430)]

df['INSPECTION'] = df['DATE_TIME'].dt.day

df['MODE'] = np.select([df['INSPECTION'] == 1, df['INSPECTION'].isin([2, 3])], ['A', 'B'], 'C')

df['TIME'] = df['DATE_TIME'].dt.time
# df['TIME'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['TIME'])
df['TIME'] = df['TIME'].astype('str')


# Create DAY Night columns only-------------------------------------------------------------------------
def cycle_day_period(dataframe: pd.DataFrame, midnight='00:00:00', start_of_morning='06:00:00',
                     start_of_afternoon='13:00:00',
                     start_of_evening='18:00:00', end_of_evening='23:00:00', start_of_night='24:00:00'):
    bins = [midnight, start_of_morning, start_of_afternoon, start_of_evening, end_of_evening, start_of_night]
    labels = ['Night', 'Morning', 'Morning', 'Night', 'Night']

    return pd.cut(
        pd.to_timedelta(dataframe),
        bins=list(map(pd.Timedelta, bins)),
        labels=labels, right=False, ordered=False
    )


df['CYCLE_PART'] = cycle_day_period(df['TIME'], '00:00:00', '06:00:00', '13:00:00', '18:00:00', '23:00:00', '24:00:00')
```

**My Expectation**: is to find most similar or same values among 'VALUE1', 'VALUE2', 'VALUE3', 'VALUE4 values. Meanwhile, Model column should be same, whereas SOLD is different.

So far, this is what I came up with:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import distance_matrix
model_groups = df.groupby(by=['MODEL'])

smallest = []
for group_name, df_model in model_groups:
    sold_1 = df_model.loc[df_model['SOLD']==1]
    sold_0 = df_model.loc[df_model['SOLD']==0]
    values_1 = sold_1[['VALUE1','VALUE2','VALUE3','VALUE4']].to_numpy()
    values_0 = sold_0[['VALUE1','VALUE2','VALUE3','VALUE4']].to_numpy()
    mtrx = distance_matrix(values_1, values_0)
    ij_min = np.unravel_index(mtrx.argmin(), mtrx.shape)
    smallest.append([group_name,sold_1.iloc[ij_min[0]], sold_0.iloc[ij_min[1]]])
```

**This script shows only 4 same distances**
How can I modify this code so that I can find closest point of a given point. I would like to either write index or a row value as input, then I owuld like to get a closest/most similar point to input. But, MODEL colun should be same and SOLD columns should be different.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve this in an efficient way with the Eucledian Distance computation, that might sound intimidating but fairly simple to implement in Pandas

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = df[(df['MODEL'] == df['MODEL']) & (df['SOLD'] != df['SOLD'])]

# Eucledian distances
df['EUCLIDEAN_DIST'] = np.sqrt(np.square(df['VALUE1'] - df['VALUE2']) + np.square(df['VALUE3'] - df['VALUE4']))

#highest distances
df = df.sort_values(by='EUCLIDEAN_DIST')
```

Is this useful to you ?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not useful, because I end up getting empty dataframe when I apply third line of your solution